# Keyframe interpolation results in bouncy feet

Tags: export, bones, keyframes, unity, interpolation

I made a very basic test model (Programmer by trade, not artist), I wrote an exporter to export the model, armature and keyframes. Everything was going pretty well until I noticed that the feet of my model were jiggling/bouncing up and down.

I noticed that if I did not interpolate between the exporter keyframes, and instead just jump from one frame to the next, all keyframes had good values and behaved exactly as they do in blender.

So far, you might think there's something up with my exporter or animation code, and that's what I was thinking as well and spent the better part of the night going through all my math code, and going as far as pulling in another library just to cross check the results.

I then got the brilliant idea to import the scene into Unity as well as Open3Mod, and noticed that they both had the exact same bouncy feet problems for the given animation, which should eliminate my code as the source of the error.

The question is, what is causing the feet to bounce? What did I do wrong with the model? The rig is extremely simple, there are two ik bones, with a pole target each for the knees, they are set up so that I can move the feet around and the thigh and calf will adjust themselves. The ankle bones are set up not to inherit rotation. Is this just a side effect from a very simplistic animation (The only bone that moves is the pelvis/root, the rest is handled by the IK constraints)

Some typical things I've already tried:

- Applying all transformations for both the armature and the mesh.
- Made sure none of the bones have any roll.
- Baked all animations (My exporter does this in effect anyway, and the keyframes are good, the problem happens between two keyframes ie. the interpolation)
- @SergeL Noticed that the tibia bone head dances around the foot ik bone slightly in blender, which is noticeable when you zoom in really close. This is however still the actual keyframe data being exported from Blender, and that possible imprecision shows no visible results outside of Blender, to be sure though: I set a limit distance constraint on the tibia bone targeting the foot ik with a distance of like 0.011, which removed any traces of jiggles in blender, but had absolutely no effect on the model in Unity or my own program.

Not entirely sure about the rules regarding this, but explaining the problem verbally with adequate detail feels diffult, so here's a video showing the problem in action, captured in my own test program for simplicity, however it looks identical in Unity: https://youtu.be/Mw2WgaQMC-Q

The ankle bone should not move at all, the magenta colored wire-line serves as a reference to show the incorrect movement more clearly.

More than willing to clarify or provide more information if needed.

I've uploaded the .blend file here:

[image]

Comment: Disabled inhereted rotation might be a problem. Check it back and try to use "Limit rotation" constraint to manage rotation of that bone

Comment: @Serge L I did try checking it yesterday, it makes the bounce less noticeable(since the foot is now rotating back and forth), but it is still there.

Comment: Could you share a file example to investigate? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: @SergeL Of course, I've updated the post. Hopefully I did it correctly.

Comment: I clearly see how Tibia.r bone is loosing connection with IK target, but really don't know why. Anyway, I have no real solution except ugly workaround: add "Damped track" constraint to Tibia, set target to Foot_IK.r (-Z axis)

Comment: @SergeL Could you explain what you mean by losing connection? Is it getting physically disconnected in blender during animation? Or is this something you noticed after exporting to some other application?

Comment: Yeah, during animation in Blender, tail of IK-constraind tibia is dancing around foot_IK's head. Find connection and go in Side ortho view (Num 5->num 3) and scroll-in for full zoom

Comment: Ah, when zooming in extremely close I can see it now. I think at that zoom level it's likely just imprecision, I can't see that in blender at the zoom levels used in my video. Blender also doesn't display sub-frames via interpolation either as far as I can tell, and the keyframes themselves do not jiggle when exported, but they are producing values, that when interpolated between, creates a jiggle.